# Split test groups base on GUID

Tags: algorithm, guid

Users in the system are identified by GUID, and with a new feature, I want to divide users into two groups - test and control.

Is there a easy way to split users into one of the two group with a 50/50 chance, based on their GUID?

e.g. If the nth character's ascii code is an odd -> test group, otherwise control group.

What about 70/30, or other ratio?

The reason I want to classify users base on GUID, is because later I can easily tell which users are in which group and compare the performance between two groups, without having to keep track of the group assignment - I simply need to calculate it again.

Comment: If you say "chance" means the final result may not be exactly equal to the ratio you want? Say just generate random number and see if it is odd or even?

Comment: it doesn't need to be exactly 50/50, just like random generate 100 of 0s and 1s doesn't mean you will get exactly 50 0s and 50 1s.

Comment: So just put user to group A if the random number is odd; to group B otherwise?

Comment: Generate an 8-bit CRC from the GUID, and then select the group based on the value of the CRC.

Comment: Any decent hash function such as an 8-bit CRC should do well. If the GUIDs are derived from a system clock the low order bits should be roughly random (although you don't know where the low changing bits are as you don't know the precision of the system clock). The other possibility is that the GUIDs are derived from a random number generator in which case a considerable number of bits really are random. In either case any decent hash function should give you a fairly evenly distributed output and you can use a lookup table addressed by this to give you whatever split you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Derek Li notes, the GUID's bits might be based on a timestamp, so you shouldn't use them directly.

The safest solution is to hash the GUID using a hash function like [MurmurHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash). This will produce a random number (but the *same* random number every time for any given GUID) which you can then use to do the split.

For example, you could do a 30/70 split like this:

```
function isInTestGroup(user) {
    var hash = murmurHash(user.guid);
    return (hash % 100) < 30; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If some character in the GUID has a 1 in 16 change of being one of the following characters: "0123456789ABCEDF", then perhaps you could test a scheme that determines placement by that character.

Say the last character of the guid called c has a 1/16 chance of being any hex digit:

for 50/50 distribution -> c <= 7 for group 1, c > 7 for group 2

for 70/30 c <= A for group 1, c > A for group 2

etc...

Comment: Yes - but which of the hexadecimal digits, or which of the bits is the best for this purpose? For example, .NET guid generator will set first 60 bits base on a timestamp, the last 48 bits are the unique address of the computer's network card, and two bits before will always be 01. So not all bits are created equal are they? :)

Comment: What if you took the sum of the characters of the guid, (short example "43AC" = 4 + 3 + 10 + 12 = 29) then modulo 16 (29 % 16 = 13) so the outcome is 13 'D'? then base it off that?  Or any kind of modulo scheme would probably work as long as the sum is evenly distributed over that range.

Comment: I see other users are noticing that a random number generator could satisfy the issue, unless there is a reason for the randomness must to be provided by the guids.

Comment: the idea is then I don't need to track which user is in which group, when I later try to compare the performance between the two groups.